# Testing reconnect with different browsers

Tags: javascript

I'm testing reconnection for my app from client side with different browsers and observing different behaviours.

Steps:

1. Connect my app to my server
2. Unplug the ethernet cable

   - Firefox: lost connection event fired immediately
   - Chrome: nothing
   - IE11: does not seem to recognise the lost connection immediately

My app attempts to reconnect right away as soon as it gets the lost connection event from the browsers.

I'm aware that this probably down to different browsers behaviour. Anything I can do from the client side to overcome the browser quirk here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unplug the ethernet cable

This probably doesn't do what you think it does.

The exact behaviour can differ between operating systems, but fundamentally & deliberately a break in the underlying media does not equate to a break in a TCP connection that is currently using it.

Prior to Windows 7 the whole NIC is closed when its cat5 lead is pulled which closed all TCP connections going through it. This can mislead people into believing they're observing a connection closure. The remote TCP peer however observes only TCP silence .. and holds the connection still in [`ESTABLISHED`](http://ssfnet.org/Exchange/tcp/Graphics/tcpStateDiagram1.gif)

To fully close the TCP connection Windows users can use [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to identify and then close the related socket. Linux users can use [`fuser`](https://superuser.com/questions/127863/manually-closing-a-port-from-commandline) to the same effect with some hoop jumping. Failing these ideas, use a simple TCP proxy between the client with server and kill that process to close the TCP connection from the browser.

**These points aside**, having reliably effected a connection closure you still need to employ a periodic application level ping to test the availability of your server as a live HTTP session does not necessarily have any live TCP connections.

Looking forward to HTML5 - a WebSocket behaves more like its underlying TCP connection and *will* notify you on closure.

Comment: :o I didn't know unplug the ethernet cable don't cause the disconnection immediately. Yes, you are right. I should have a client side ping to monitor the connection with my server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Offline.js?](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/) Depending on your ultimate use case, that might solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen a socket and when you get an error on listening you can do what you want. [JQuery.webSocket](https://github.com/clickalicious/jQuery.WebSocket) can be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you can send an AJAX request every few seconds to the server to check the connection status.

```
window.myInterval = setInterval(
    function() {
        $.ajax(
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://your.server.io/test_url.php",
            statusCode: {
                503: function() {
                    alert("Service Unavailable");
                    // your code
                }
            }
        );
    }
, 5000);
```

It is easily tweakable to capture connection lost and back up events.

```
window.connectionUp = true;
window.myInterval = setInterval(
    function() {
        $.ajax(
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://your.server.io/test_url.php",
            statusCode: {
                503: function() {
                    alert("Service Unavailable");
                    window.connectionUp = false;
                    // your code
                }
                200: function() {
                    alert("Service Available");
                    if (window.connectionUp = false) {
                        // reconnect
                    }
                    window.connectionUp = true;
                    // your code
                }
            }
        );
    }
, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! It seems this is the way to go for me.